# SQL: Get count of rows where ID matches ID in a reference table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've got two tables:

- `bid_tag`
- `bid_tag_design`

  bid_tag:
  id, tag_design, tag_size, user_id, reserved

  big_tag_design:
  id, name

I want to be able to query how many tag designs there are of each within the bid_tag table `WHERE user_id = 0 AND reserved = 0`

I'll then use the query to create a `CRON` Job for a daily report of stock levels...

Comment: what are the columns in each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment it seems the link between the tables is the other way around. So I changed the query to take the schema into account and it should be working with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as nbDesigns, bid_tag_design.id, bid_tag_design.name
FROM bid_tag_design
  LEFT JOIN bid_tag ON bid_tag.tag_design = bid_tag_design.id
WHERE bid_tag.user_id = 0 AND bid_tag.reserved = 0
GROUP BY bid_tag.tag_design
```

let's say you have this in bid_tag_design :

```
id | name
1  | design 1
2  | design 2
```

And then this in bid_tag

```
id | tag_design | user | reserved
1  | 1          | 0    | 0
2  | 1          | 0    | 0
3  | 2          | 0    | 0
4  | 2          | 0    | 0
5  | 1          | 1    | 0
6  | 2          | 2    | 0
7  | 1          | 0    | 0
8  | 1          | 0    | 0
9  | 1          | 3    | 0
```

Then the result of the second query should be

```
nbDesigns | id | name
4         | 1  | design 1
2         | 2  | design 2
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT( * ) AS nbDesigns, bid_tag.id
FROM bid_tag
LEFT JOIN bid_tag_design ON bid_tag.id = bid_tag_design.id
WHERE bid_tag.user_id =0
AND bid_tag.reserved =0
GROUP BY bid_tag.id` - What that gives me is a row for each result ... is there not a way to return a row for each design with the amount as a column?

Comment: What about the new query? I thought your table was linked in the other order  1 tag for N designs, instead of 1 design for N tags

Comment: Take a look at my edit in the post. `bid_tag_design` contains two columns: `id` and `name` ... I need to be able to display each row as follows: `tag_id, tag_name, count`

Comment: that's exactly what does my second query (after the edit)

Comment: Here's the proper query: `SELECT COUNT( * ) AS nbDesigns, bid_tag_design.id, bid_tag_design.name
FROM bid_tag_design
LEFT JOIN bid_tag ON bid_tag.tag_design = bid_tag.tag_design
WHERE bid_tag.user_id =0
AND bid_tag.reserved =0
GROUP BY bid_tag_design.id` - but each row shows ALL tags in the first column. It seems to be spitting out the total.

Comment: this is NOT correct. Look at your "JOIN" condition, you say the same statement on both side of the equal sign

Comment: I just used what you gave me. And the result (after updating the references) is that each row displays the TOTAL tag count, not the count of each `tag_design`

Comment: what do you mean by "the total tag count" ? the total number of line in the bid_tag table ?

Comment: In other words ... the total count of tags `WHERE user_id = 0 AND reserved = 0` is `1739`. And that's the number that is being given for each row.

Comment: ok, try to change the GROUP BY clause, I think I'm wrong. Replace it with   GROUP BY bid_tag.tag_design

Comment: Closer, but now that's giving me the total number of those tags, regardless of `reserved` or `user_id`

Comment: Change your updated query to: `SELECT COUNT( * ) AS nbDesigns, bid_tag_design.id, bid_tag_design.name
FROM bid_tag_design
LEFT JOIN bid_tag ON bid_tag.tag_design = bid_tag_design.id
WHERE bid_tag.user_id =0
AND bid_tag.reserved =0
GROUP BY bid_tag.tag_design` and it seems to be working! :)

Comment: oh snap, sorry, I forgot to update the JOIN condition based on your real schema. That's why you JOIN condition was not correct in one of your comment, I corrected it

Comment: And the first line has a spelling mistake of `big_` instead of `bid`. THANKS!

Comment: if you're able ... could you tell me how I might be able to include the counts of two other columns? `tag_size` within the `bid_tag` table. So the results would look like this: `total|id|name|small (total)|large (total)`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do here. What are the possibile values of the column tag_size? just small/large? You might be better off writing a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the count and not the count by tag, then something like:

```
select count(*)
from bid_tag_design
where user_id = 0 and reserved = 0
```

does it, assuming that user_id and reserved are in that table.  You only need the join if bid_tag has one or both of these fields, something like:

```
select count(*)
from bid_tag bt join
     bid_tag_design btd
     on bt.bid_tag_id = btd.bid_tag_id
where bt.user_id = 0 and btd.reserved = 0
```

If you want a row for each design, then group by that:

```
select btd.bid_tag_design_id, count(*)
```

from bid_tag bt join
         bid_tag_design btd
         on bt.bid_tag_id = btd.bid_tag_id
    where bt.user_id = 0 and btd.reserved = 0

Comment: `SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM bid_tag bt
JOIN bid_tag_design btd ON bt.tag_design = btd.id
WHERE bt.user_id =0
AND bt.reserved = 0` - This just gives me a total count. What I'm looking for is a row for each design with the count

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     select tag_design ,count(tag_design) countdesign
     from bid_tag
     where user_id = 0 and reserved = 0
     group by tag_design
```

Comment: that just gives me a total count. I need each design on it's own row with it's own count.

Comment: look my edit if it works for u.